# Bottom sheet STATE_EXPENDED kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to expend my bottom sheet using the below code it is expanded only to fill the content in the sheet. example if there are 3 items in my list then it will expand say till mid of the screen and if there are 10 it will expand fully and will be scrollable. [this is my xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiazb.png)

I tried multiple solutions on the internet but nothing is working in my case.

````
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
//dialog.behavior.peekHeight = getApplicationContext().resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels // tried this too
        dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        return dialog
    }```
````

Comment: I'm opening this dialog from another fragment using 
"mydialogInstance.show((childFragmentManager, mydialogbottomsheet.javaClass.name)"

Comment: What solution exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want my bottom sheet to expand till top. which only happens when the content in the bottom sheet is filling the parent screen.

Answer (score 0):

Define a theme for `bottomsheet` to give the `peekheight` a desired value. Like so;

```
style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog"> 
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/SheetStyle</item>
</style> 


<style name="SheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal"> 
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">600</item>  
</style>
```

The `peekheight` attribute determines the height of your bottom sheet. You can set it to a value of your choosing.

Then in your `app theme`, make the following declaration:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>
```